# Finding two languages satisfying conditions

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, computability

> Let $$E_{TM} = \left \{ \langle M\rangle \mid L(M) = \emptyset \right\}$$
>
> Prove that there are two languages $L_1, L_2$ such that
>
> 1. $L_1, L_2 $ are infinite.
> 2. $L_1 \cup L_2 = E_{TM}$
> 3. $L_1 \cap L_2 = \emptyset$
> 4. $L_1$ is decidable, $L_2$ is not recognizable.

I'm finding it really hard to find two languages that satisfy these conditions.

Especially the second condition, which two language unify to $E_{TM}$?

Comment: Hint 1, can you construct one $M$ such that $L(M)=\emptyset$? Hint 2, can you construct infinitely many such $M$? Hint 3, let $L_2=E_{TM}\setminus L_1$.

Comment: If you has figured out this problem, please write an answer (yes, you can answer your own question).

Comment: Certainly, I will

Comment: The padding lemma states that there is a total computable function that given any (encoding of) TM $M$, it returns a TM $N$ having a "longer" encoding than the one of $M$, where $L(M)=L(N)$. Essentially, the function adds a few redundant states to $M$ to make its encoding "longer". You could try to apply this function many times, iterating it.

Comment: Hint: Another way to build $L_1$ without using the padding argument is using the set of accepting states $F$ ... what happens if $F = \emptyset$ ...?

Comment: @Alan can you please share where is this question taken from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight improvement:

$L_2 = E_{TM} \backslash L_1 $ (since we require that $L_1 \cap L_2 = \emptyset$).

$L_1$ must be a language of turing machines, i.e. $L_1 = \{\langle M\rangle \mid \dots\} $, so that $L_1 \cup L_2 = E_{TM}$.

So let's set $L_1 =$ $\{\langle M\rangle\mid  C_0\text{ is a reject state}\}$.

The following holds:

- $L_1 $ is infinite and decidable (easy to decide given $M$, what the configuration of the first state is).
- $L_2 $ is infinite and unrecognizable.